# How to use one SASS mixin file across all projects so that it's easier to add mixins and use it in older projects

Tags: sass

When I start a new design project, I start with my existing boilerplate i.e sass(partials/mixins, partials/reset, partials/variables) etc.

The problem  is if I add new mixins to `mixins.scss` in my current project, to use the new mixin for my older projects I have to manually copy new mixins in the old `mixin.scss` in that project.

I have several projects and it becomes a headache to update mixins as described above.

What I'd like is to manage one central mixin file that all projects (new and old ones) can pull in from a centralized remote repo (in github)

one SASS mixin file across all projects so that it's easier to add mixins and use it in older projects

Is it possible with current version of SASS or any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you use a tool such as Grunt or Gulp? If you are using one of these I recommend to set up your own development flow. This way you can make a mixin file that will be ready to go with every project.

Comment: @Gramm, Yes I do use grunt for concatenation, minification etc but I am not sure how grunt can be used as tool/soln to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the [Import](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) imo.

Create a file which should contains all your mixins (eitheir directly or by importing them from other files) and import that file wherever you want all your mixins to be available

Comment: If I read correctly, he does that but wants to auto-update the file.

Comment: I think the answer is in his question "manage one central mixin file". If that file is in a globally available location it should work (import <absolute path to file>)

Comment: @SergeBuSI, using `import` just adds the statement to my compiled css, for eg: `import  url('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Victa/1632210/raw/5841dec216dbec1bd60dba2fb1621052bd8e1489/_media-object.scss');` it does not let me use the media object mixin in my `style.scss` defined in the imported file.

Comment: @dkjain That's just weird. It should work. You don't need to add the extension `.scss`, maybe that's the culprit.